# Extra space with parcolumns

Tags: parcolumns

I am preparing my CV and I am encountering an extra space at the start of each line in each of the `colchunks` of `parcolumns`. The following image says it all:

[image]

Notice extra space in from of P or Project and S of Some. Note this happens with the first line only. `noindent` does not help either. Here's my piece of code that produces this block:

```
\begin{parcolumns}[rulebetween, nofirstindent, colwidths={1=.15\linewidth}]{2}
  \colchunk[1]{
  \noindent PROJECT\\*
  WORK
  }
  \colchunk[2]{
  Some project work here.\\*
  Some project work here.
  }
\end{parcolumns}
```

Comment: you mean `parcolumns` in your opening sentence.

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing that out. I have edited that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the spurious blank spaces (a "carriage return" is taken as a single space) using `%`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{parcolumns}

\begin{document}

\begin{parcolumns}[rulebetween, nofirstindent, colwidths={1=.15\linewidth}]{2}
  \colchunk[1]{%
  PROJECT\\*
  WORK%
  }
  \colchunk[2]{%
  Some project work here.\\*
  Some project work here.%
  }
\end{parcolumns}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the fix. Can you explain why this happens?

Comment: @abhinavkulkarni: I already explained in my answer. In text mode, a carriage return will be taken as a blank space; adding `%` prevents those undesired spaces.